# what changes i have to do to make my search bar work?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I made a search bar which is not working on pressing enter for first time.
But if i will click maginifier button for the first time and then after this if i will search by pressing enter it will work. Why is it ?
setSearchValue() method is setting the value in a variable and applySearchOnEnter() method is used for searching a term by pressing enter.
Here is my Ts code

```
  applySearchOnEnter() {
    this.searchTerm = this.searchValue;
    if (this.searchTerm.length >= this.minSearchLength) {
      this.applySearch();
    }
  }


  //responsible for handling search functionality
  applySearch() {
    console.log("i am here 2");
    this.makeThingsReadyForSearch();
    this.filterCustomers(this.selected);
  }

  //clear previously applied search type filter
  makeThingsReadyForSearch() {
    console.log("i am here 3");
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.canClear = true;
    this.masterAccounts = [];
    this.masterAccounts.push(...this.masterAccountsArray);
    console.log(this.masterAccounts);
    console.log(this.masterAccountsArray);
  }

  //clear filter applied and reset customers data
  resetOnEmptySearch() {
    if (this.canClear && this.searchTerm.length == 0) {
      this.resetAll();
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  //filtering customers data based on the search type applied
  filterCustomers(key: string) {
    let masterAccountsArray1: MasterAccount[] = [];

    this.masterAccountsArray.forEach(masterAccounts => {
      if (masterAccounts[key] != ''
        && masterAccounts[key] != null
        && masterAccounts[key].toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        masterAccountsArray1.push(masterAccounts);
      }
    });
    this.masterAccountsArray = masterAccountsArray1;
    console.log("masterAccountsArray is: ",  this.masterAccountsArray);
    this.isLoading = false;
  }

  //clear data on cancel button
  resetOnClearFilter() {
    this.resetAll();
    this.searchTerm = '';
    this.isLoading = false;
  }

  //will remove any search filter applied and reset all data
  resetAll() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.canClear = false;
    this.masterAccountsArray = [];
    this.masterAccountsArray.push(...this.masterAccounts);
  }

  //holds searchTerm value to apply filtration
  setSearchValue(value: string) {
    this.searchValue = value;
    console.log("search value in start is: " , this.searchValue);
  }

}

and below is the html

    <div style="font-size: 1em; display: inline-block;">
      <mat-form-field class="form-field-style" appearance="outline">
        <span matPrefix> </span>
        <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
        <mat-placeholder>Search</mat-placeholder>
        <input
          #searchInput
          type="text"
          matInput
          name="search"
          [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
          (keyup.backspace)="resetOnEmptySearch()"
          (keydown.enter)="setSearchValue(searchInput.value)"
          (keyup.enter)="applySearchOnEnter()"
        >
        <button
          *ngIf="searchTerm != ''"
          matSuffix
          class="clear-button-style icon-display-cross"
          (click)="resetOnClearFilter()"
        >
          <mat-icon style="color: #777777">clear</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button
          class="space-button"
          matSuffix>
        </button>

        <button
          *ngIf="searchTerm.length < minSearchLength;
        else enableSearchButton"
          disabled
          matSuffix
          class="clear-button-style icon-display-search">
          <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <ng-template #enableSearchButton>
          <button
            class="clear-button-style icon-display-search"
            matSuffix
            (click)="applySearch()"
          >
            <mat-icon style="color: red;">search</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```